# Type Error memory is not converted into struct storage

Tags: solidity, contract-development, transactions

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.17;


contract hoteltranscation  {

  struct hotel{
    string HotelName;
    uint256 BookingNumber;
  }

   function HotelBooking(string _HotelName,uint256 _BookingNumber ) public   {
     hotel storage addtrascation =  hotel (_HotelName,_BookingNumber);
   }
}
```

I have declared a struct as  public varable  and i want to use it as storage  variable inside a function

2) I am getting the following error

```
':12:6: TypeError: Type struct hoteltranscation.hotel memory is not implicitly convertible to expected type struct hoteltranscation.hotel storage pointer.\n     hotel storage addtrascation =  hotel (_HotelName,_BookingNumber);\
```

3) I want to make the state varables as storage  varables and store some data

Comment: . i have updted the question i want to create a varable refrence to state varable inside the function so to reduce the gas consuming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking a stab in the dark to what you are trying to do here, feel free to update your question, and I can either remove my answer or update it.

It looks like you want to input the values of a `hotel` struct, and then store that somewhere permanently, maybe an array of hotel bookings.

You can do that like this:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.17;

contract hoteltranscation  {

    struct hotel{
        string HotelName;
        uint256 BookingNumber;
    }

    hotel[] HotelBookings;

    function HotelBooking(string _HotelName, uint256 _BookingNumber) public   {
        HotelBookings.push(hotel (_HotelName, _BookingNumber));
    }

    function GetHotelBooking(uint _num) public view returns(string, uint256) {
        return (HotelBookings[_num].HotelName, HotelBookings[_num].BookingNumber);
    }
}
```

No need to get too fancy here. If for some reason you need to use a temporary variable before you push to the global array, that would be a perfect use of a memory variable:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.17;

contract hoteltranscation  {

    struct hotel{
        string HotelName;
        uint256 BookingNumber;
    }

    hotel[] HotelBookings;

    function HotelBooking(string _HotelName, uint256 _BookingNumber) public   {

        hotel memory tempHotel = hotel (_HotelName, _BookingNumber);
        // Do some logic
        HotelBookings.push(tempHotel);
    }

    function GetHotelBooking(uint _num) public view returns(string, uint256) {
        return (HotelBookings[_num].HotelName, HotelBookings[_num].BookingNumber);
    }
}
```

Does this help?

Comment: Thanks 

Means when storing with  data of  struct  we use array or mapping is it correct

Comment: You don't have to. You can also store just a single value (`hotel SingleHotelBooking;`), but it probably makes sense to put it in the "contract context" so that it is stored in the contract and accessible from other functions. Maybe [read this for more details](https://medium.com/coinmonks/ethereum-solidity-memory-vs-storage-which-to-use-in-local-functions-72b593c3703a) on the `memory` and `storage` keyword.

Comment: Here is a relevant quote from the article: `storage cannot be newly created in a function. Any storage referenced variable in a function always refers a piece of data pre-allocated on the contract storage (state variable). Any mutation persists after function call.`

Comment: Sorry for bothering you

But should we  mandtery name array and struct same name  does  it have any link

Comment: Sorry, I didn't quite understand your question,  but the naming of variables, structs, and arrays are all independent of one another. They just need to be consistent.

Comment: Thanks i got it 

hotel[] HotelBookings in place of type of varable beside the Array  you mentoined the name of struct so the type will be struct right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84899/discussion-between-md-venkatesh-and-shawn-tabrizi).